# Elegant way to fillna missing values for dates in spark

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, fillna

Let me break this problem down to a smaller chunk. I have a DataFrame in PySpark, where I have a column `arrival_date` in `date` format -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
values = [('22.05.2016',),('13.07.2010',),('15.09.2012',),(None,)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['arrival_date'])

#Following code line converts String into Date format
df = df.withColumn('arrival_date',to_date(col('arrival_date'),'dd.MM.yyyy'))
df.show()
+------------+
|arrival_date|
+------------+
|  2016-05-22|
|  2010-07-13|
|  2012-09-15|
|        null|
+------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- arrival_date: date (nullable = true)
```

After applying a lot of transformations to the DataFrame, I finally wish to fill in the missing dates, marked as `null` with `01-01-1900`.

**One method** to do this is to convert the column `arrival_date` to `String` and then replace missing values this way - `df.fillna('1900-01-01',subset=['arrival_date'])` and finally reconvert this column `to_date`. This is very unelegant.

The following code line doesn't work, as expected and I get an error-

```
df = df.fillna(to_date(lit('1900-01-01'),'yyyy-MM-dd'), subset=['arrival_date'])
```

The documentation says  [The value must be of the following type: Int, Long, Float, Double, String, Boolean.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html)

**Another way** is by using `withColumn()` and `when()` -

```
df = df.withColumn('arrival_date',when(col('arrival_date').isNull(),to_date(lit('01.01.1900'),'dd.MM.yyyy')).otherwise(col('arrival_date')))
```

Is there a way, where I could directly assign a date of my choice to a `date` formatted column by using some function?

Anyone has any better suggestion?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Last time till I used to work with PySpark, I could not find a simple solution to it. May be in the last 2 years they have something in the new release, don't know.

Answer (score 4):

The second way should be the way to do it, but you don't have to use to_date to transform between string and date, just use datetime.date(1900, 1, 1).

```
import datetime as dt
df = df.withColumn('arrival_date', when(col('arrival_date').isNull(), dt.date(1900, 1, 1)).otherwise(col('arrival_date')))
```

Comment: Hello. If you read the question carefully, I have already mentioned this solution under caption ‘Another way’. But, that’s something I wanted to avoid. I wanted to use .fillna() directly time solve this, avoiding if/else.

Comment: This is the solution I need. Perfect!